# B'rashith (Genesis) 27.28 - the Hebrew rule of grammar, is it a vav sheva or a vav patach?

Tags: hebrew, grammar-dikduk

is the Hebrew rule of grammar always consistent when it lays down the rule  that "no two shevas begin a word?" For example, Brashith (Genesis) 27.28 uses the vav sheva followed by a yud sheva. Shouldn't this be read *kri* (pronounced) vav patach "vav hahipuch" rather than read as written *k'tiv* vav sheva (vav hachibur)?

Comment: Can you quote the word or phrase you refer to? I see no double Shva in Gen 27:28

Comment: ve'ye'ten וְיִתֶּן

Comment: The Yud in that word has a Chirik, not a Sheva. Whats the problem? It's pronounced w'yitten, meaning: and he will give.

Comment: As I understand Hebrew grammar, the rule is that a word cannot have two Sheva's at the beginning of it and where a yud follows the vav, the dagesh is dropped. therefore our passuk could be read, "And G-D has given the dew...."

Because in vaytzav (Deut. 31:10) ('and then he [Moshe] commanded) the Dagesh is omitted and in Genesis 27.27 the yud has the dagesh dropped, we see that, PAST TENSE, Ya'acov is already blessed before what is spoken of in our passuk 27.28 and therefore, what was spoken of in 28 must be read as if it [the blessing] were already to have taken place.

Comment: You didn't respond to my comment. Do you have any examples of two Shevas in a row or not? Why are you citing a word that doesn't have that property?

Comment: because the dagesh is dropped, doesn't the yud have to compensate for the loss of the dagesh? 27.27 וַיְבָרְכֵהוּ gives us the continuous action Rashi speaks of in his comments

Comment: @DoubleAA ^^^^^. Yochanan, if you want a user to be informed of your comment, make sure to put a @ in front of his username, as I did in the beginning of this comment.

Comment: @YochananMauritzHummasti No one has any idea what you're talking about. There is no Dagesh that is dropped in וְיִתֶּן.

Answer (score 1):

וְיִתֶּן  is a jussive, the translation therefore "May He (G'd) give" (and not: He will give)

Answer (score 0):

There is (kind of) one exception to that rule, but ויתן is not it.  It's in Haazinu 32:5:

> הַ לְיְהוָה תִּגְמְלוּ-זֹאת

(I say "kind of" because ה לה' is read as one word.)

Comment: Moreover the Sheva under the Yud is really a Chataf Patach under an Alef.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes but a chataf patach is a type of sheva anyway